# Adjust mega menu li responsively so that li's reduce equally

Tags: css

I've been scratching my head with this one for a while. I need to make a ul li menu reduce width responsively. At the moment the last li wraps to another line as the screen width is reduced. Whilst I've managed to do it on one of my menus, the same type of css won't work on this as the li contents are not equally sized. I did find a fiddle from a previous SO question, but trying  that method it completely breaks the styling of the dropdown for "Shop By Products"

I'm trying to achieve something like this as the viewport is reduced.
http://jsfiddle.net/au9muz43/
where the css is very simple as

```
.horizontal-style {
display: table;
width: 100%
}
.horizontal-style li {
display: table-cell;
}
.horizontal-style a {
display: block;
border: 1px solid red;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 5px;
background: #999
}
```

I've set up a fiddle with a large chunk of my css and html here: https://jsfiddle.net/1Le63xk0/1/

Even adding

```
display:table-cell;
```

to my css line

```
.mega-menu li{float:left;text-align:center;position:relative;margin-right:15px;border:none;}
```

breaks the dropdown layout for the Products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a quick combining of the two fiddles, I noticed that some of the styles conflicted. I removed your `display:block` calls on the li / a, and made them `display:table-cell;` (which is the reason why it will shrink, instead of drop to a new line.

Brought all your css over, this was just a case of fixing certain divs that were still styled as block/inline-block and converting them to table formats.

The main issues were found in these lines:

```
.mega-menu li a{color:#fff;outline:0;padding:12px 35px 0px 0px;text-decoration:none;display:block;font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;}

.mega-menu li:hover a{color:#007dc5;position:relative;z-index:11;padding:4px 11px 3px 11px;}
```

Where you had a large amount of padding that was pushing each div.

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au9muz43/8/)**.

**Edit:** Updated just to bring more of his css over.

**Edit 2:** Still getting downvoted, there literally is no other way to explain it other than, double checking OPs `display` properties. OP hasn't responded explaining something is wrong with the fiddle, so as far as I can see, it has everything he asked for: A shrinking nav, with his dropdowns working the same.

Comment: This is actually the answer that does what the question asked, so no idea why someone chose to down vote it. I will need to do some tweaking to the css to tidy up the hover actions etc, but it does function as I need.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your answer. It does precisely what I had asked for. Nav li's shrink as the width is reduced and the dropdown still functions correctly. I see no reason for downvotes, other than spite.

Answer (score 0):

First: there is a `;` missing on `width:100%`. Secondly it can be solved by changing display to block and inline-block. The table display is for tables and (probably) not intended to be used in this case.

```css
.horizontal-style {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.horizontal-style li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;

}
.horizontal-style a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #999
}

div {
    background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop By Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop By Brand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why Choose Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Take a better look in [this JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ks1z3dq1/) StackOverflow snippet does not support resizing.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my issue. My html and css is the second fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1Le63xk0/1/
The other was an example of how I needed my menu to resize.

Comment: Still. Change to block and inline-block and it will work

Comment: Well not exactly. If you look at the original fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/au9muz43/) it doesn't wrap as screen width is reduced. Instead the li width is reduced.

Comment: horizontal style block ||| horizontal style a inline-block. That pushes the elements down when the space is gone